# C# date formats for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have dates in SQL stored as DateTime,
when showing them in a textbox I do this:

```
txtDateLogged.Text = v.DateLogged.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

But when I the update that textbox to write back to SQL Im getting and invalid DateTime error when using this:

```
if (DateLogged!= "")
{ 
     uInput.DateLogged = Convert.ToDateTime(DateLogged);
}
```

Im assuming Im missing something in the formatting - the date value is passed into the public void doing the update as a string, then converted in the line above.
Any suggestions?

thanks

T

Comment: Did you try `DateTime.ParseExact` ?

Comment: Could be that you are just missing the single quotes around the date? Otherwise I know the sql server on my system like it's dates like this: 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert *back* in the same format that you converted *to* text, e.g.

```
uInput = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See the docs for [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) for more details.

Of course, if you could *avoid* converting to a string representation - or keep the `DateTime` as well - that would be better.

If you're parsing *user input* you should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) instead, to account for the possibility of invalid data without using exceptions for flow control.

Comment: Very nice! I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use:

```
 uInput.DateLogged = (new DateTime(year, month, day))
```

And extract the year/month/day parts from DateLogged.

**EDIT:**

Since you know the date in your string is "dd-MM-yyyy", then this is how you extract the parts:

```
int year = Convert.ToInt16(DateLogged.Substring(6, 4));
int month = Convert.ToInt16(DateLogged.Substring(3, 2));
int day = Convert.ToInt16(DateLogged.Substring(0, 2));
```

If by MM you mean "JA" - then you need to convert "JA" to "01" or 1.

Comment: I like to use this approach because it negates the effect of US/UK date formats.

Comment: You're not addressing the question, which is extracting the values from the *text*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) and parse string value using `CultureInfo`.

 *User* will be able to input data using culture specific formatting and that you can just convert it to [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) :

```
 DateTime b;
 bool isCorrectValue = false;
 CultureInfo uiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
 if (DateTime.TryParse(DateLogged, uiCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out b))
     isCorrectValue = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL convert Date filed in **105** Format

e.g.

> select Convert(varchar(20),getdate(),**105**)